# url to find file path in admin dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, url

where should i look for this file in project directory as i'm in this url `index.php/admin/qquoteadv/edit/id/125/key/random-key`

I couldn't find a `qquoteadvController` & `editAction`.

Comment: search in your files for the text `qquoteadv`. It will give you at least the module it uses it.

Answer (score 1):

This route is part of [cart2quote.](http://www.cart2quote.com/) If I remember correctly the vendor space is Ophilia.

Comment: Yeah, found it in `Ophirah`.